# Group by day and left outer join the whole

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, hiveql

The data like

```
mdn day flag
c 20180302 0
c 20180303 1
b 20180303 0
a 20180301 1
b 20180301 0
a 20180302 1
```

I get the whole by select distinct mdn from data, and left join every day, how to realize it by using hive? As following, it's only one day sample:

```
with temp as (select distinct mdn from data)
select * from  temp b
left outer join
(select * from data where day=20180302) a
on a.mdn=b.mdn
```

The result of one day like:

```
c c 20180302 0
a a 20180302 1
b null null null
```

Exactly, it is just one day, and I want to get 'b null 20180302 null'

Comment: replace `null` with day value Isnull(day,'20180302')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate all the combinations:

```
select m.mdn, d.day, data.flag
from (select distinct mdn from data) m cross join
     (select distinct day from data) d left join
     data 
     on data.mdn = m.mdn and data.day = d.day ;
```

Comment: Just now I tink out of this code with mdnt as (select distinct mdn from abc)
,dayt as (select distinct day from abc)
select * from dayt a
join
mdnt b
on 1=1
left outer join
abc c
on b.mdn=c.mdn and a.day=c.day

Comment: Thank you! Your result is more simplier